# How to print dictionary items from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have this data:

```
data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20},  {'name': 'Phil', 'age': 21},  {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 42}]
```

and I am aiming to produce the following output:

```
1 - Bob is 20
2 - Phil is 21
3 - Jane is 42
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html):

```
data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20},
        {'name': 'Phil', 'age': 21},
        {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 42}]

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    print(f"{i+1} - {d['name']} is {d['age']}")
```

Output:

```
1 - Bob is 20
2 - Phil is 21
3 - Jane is 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    print(f"{i+1} - {item['name']} is {item['age']}")
#1 - Bob is 20
#2 - Phil is 21
#3 - Jane is 42
```

Comment: May I ask.. why is that??

Comment: yeah ... sure. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times when dealing with iterators, we also get a need to keep a count of iterations. Python eases the programmers’ task by providing a built-in function `enumerate()` for this task.
`Enumerate()` method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of `enumerate object`. This enumerate object can then be used directly in for loops or be converted into a list of tuples using `list()` method. You can try it:

```
data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20},  {'name': 'Phil', 'age': 21},  {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 42}]


for key, value in enumerate(data):
     print(f"{key+1} - {value['name']} is {value['age']}")
```

Output will be:

```
1 - Bob is 20
2 - Phil is 21
3 - Jane is 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post what you have already tried. If you have not tried something, your should try something first.

That being said, you essentially need to do 2 things:

- iterate over a list
- iterate over a dictionary

Assuming you're on python 3:

```
for element in data:
   for key, value in element.items():
      print(f"This is the key: {key} and this is the value: {value}")
```

The outer loop iterates over your data variable, one element at a time. It put the value each element in a variable `element`.

In this case, `element` is a dictionary. The inner loop iterates over each component of that dictionary. A dictionary has 2 elements (the key, and a value corresponding). It then puts each key into a variable, `key`, and the corresponding value of that key into a variable `value`.

The names key, value are arbitrary and you could name then foo, bar if you wanted to.

Note that both in the case of the `element` in the list and the `value` in the dictionary, the type could be anything.

EDIT: the last print uses neat formatting for later python version. You can have a string preceded with `f`, and then use {} to put a python expression withing the bracket. this is why print(f"this is the {key}") will return a print expression for the variable `key` and not the word key itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code also

```
for i in range(len(data)):
print(str(i+1)+" - "+data[i]["name"]+" is "+str(data[i]["age"]))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20},  
        {'name': 'Phil', 'age': 21},  
        {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 42}]

for idx, dic in enumerate(data, 1):
    print(f"{idx} - dic['name'] is dic['age']")
```

Comment: You almost got it, but the string formatting needs more attention. The current code will print literally `1 - dic['name'] is dic['age']`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.